# .PFM font in Jtextpane in java

Tags: java

I am creating a Rich text editor in java where i have to use pfm font in `jtextPane` .how can i use it? I previously used ttf font, it works fine.but as industry standard i have to use pfm  font

```
   String fName = "d:\\CHANK___0.PFM"        
   Font  font = new  Font(bf, 12, Font.NORMAL);
   fonts = font ;
```

but when i write `textPane.setFont(font)`  it shows an error

Comment: post the error message that you are getting

Comment: hi any body use pfm font in jtext pane in java.